# How can I solve this w forEach in js? Or any other alternative methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, foreach

Exercise and my solutions is below. I was wondering how I cd do this by using forEach **without** using a variable to store the result. Also any other possible solution is appreciated, so I can learn multiple ways to solve this. thank u!!!

Complete the function holidays that accepts an array of strings and iterates through the array. If the array contains the string "October", return "Happy Halloween". Otherwise, return the string "Have a great day!". Do not use a variable to store the result that you are returning.

```
function holidays(arr) {
  // Do not use a variable to store your result 
  // ADD CODE HERE
  if (arr.includes("October") === true) {
    return "Happy Halloween";
  } else {
    return "Have a great day!";
  }
}

// Uncomment these to check your work!
const months = ["April", "May", "June", "October"];
const animals = ["Cats", "Dogs", "Pigs"];
console.log(holidays(months)); // should return: "Happy Halloween"
console.log(holidays(animals)); // should return: "Have a great day!"
```

Comment: `myArray.forEach(functionToRun)` - Consider reading [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: This is an opinion, but `for ... of` is in almost all regards superior to `Array.prototype.forEach`, so much, that i rarely see the latter used at all anymore.

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what problem you're having with your code.  What variable are you trying to eliminate?  Where is the array iteration?

Comment: you are already reaching the result using "arr.includes()" function which is the easiest way and you are doing it without holding the result in a variable. Please Make your question more clear. What you do want to achieve ? is it just different ways to solve it ?  you can also use "arr.filtering()" :  months.filter(x =>  x=='October') . This should result in a an array which holds members/items equals to 'OCtober'. If it is an empty array you know it does not include the target word.

Comment: this should work :    `const holidays = arr => {
      return arr.filter( item => item === 'October').length >= 1 ? "Happy..." : "great day";
     }`

Comment: @ASDFGerte, I tried to solve it w forEach first and thought I must be doing sth wrong, cuz it worked in a similar exercise before ,not this time. Thx for letting me know that forEach  is not used often, I'll not spend much time on that.

Comment: @CharlesC. thx a ton for arr.filter() option & for the complete code, I wdn't be able to come up w it (at least in this week:)) greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: @AntiqTech I am so new that I am not even sure if my answer was an okay one, even tho I reached the solution. thx for that + thx for explaining the filter() method. Much appreciated!!

Comment: @devlincarnate thank u so much for taking the time to respond, problem solved. Greatly appreciated!